# Accumulating errors using ErrorT

Tags: haskell, exception, monads, either

Is it possible to accumulate error messages in the ErrorT monad? I would like to accumulate more that one error.

Comment: `Either` / `ExceptT` / `ErrorT` are inherently designed to be short-circuiting, so the answer is “no”. If you want to accumulate multiple errors, though, you should use a different monad/monad transformer, in this case probably `WriterT`.

Comment: Is it difficult to replace ErrorT with WriterT ?  At this moment I have "tower: of monad (StateT, ErrorT, IO)

Comment: It’s not difficult in the sense that it’s mechanically difficult, but it could be difficult in the sense that `ErrorT` and `WriterT` have extremely different semantics. The whole point of `ErrorT` is that it allows computations to fail. If you want to accumulate more than one error, then that means you probably want computation to keep going. Consider what implications that has for your code—can you really keep going after a failure? If the answer is “sometimes”, you might need a mixture of `WriterT` and `ExceptT` (`ErrorT` is deprecated by the way, use `ExceptT` instead).

Comment: So what do you mean by "accumulate more than one error"? The idea of an error is that execution ends immediately, so once you have a single error you can't have any more.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `Errors` Applicative from [`Control.Applicative.Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html) from *transformers*:

```
ghci> import Control.Applicative
ghci> import Control.Applicative.Lift
ghci> failure ['a'] *> pure () <* failure ['b']
Other (Constant "ab")
```

It returns the list of errors, if there are any, or the successful result.

This type is usually known as the "Validation" Applicative. There are [other implementations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation) of it available on Hackage. One posible improvement is to relax the requirement for the failure container to be a `Monoid`, allowing `Semigroup`s as well.

Notice that the `Errors` type is not a `Monad`. But you can combine it with other `Applicative`s using `Data.Functor.Compose`.

---

The `MonadPlus` instance for `ExceptT` has a related but not identical behaviour: it returns the first success, if there is any, or a list of errors:

```
ghci> throwE ['a'] `mplus` return () `mplus` throwE ['b'] :: ExceptT [Char] Identity ()
ExceptT (Identity (Right ()))
ghci> throwE ['a'] `mplus` throwE ['b'] :: ExceptT [Char] Identity ()
ExceptT (Identity (Left "ab"))
```